# Bot Framework v4 Bot emulator authentication bad request

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework v4 and Bot Emulator to test authentication. My app is based on the bot authentication sample app on [git hub](https://aka.ms/v4cs-bot-auth-sample). When I click on `Sign In` card received on the bot emulator, I receive `Bad Request` as a response on the sign-in window opened by the emulator. In the inspector pane, I see the sign-in link is given as `https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin={some value}`. This link redirects to `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/login` which results in `Bad Request`.

Any ideas whats going wrong?

[**Update**] I read the post for [`Testing authentication to your bot using the Bot Framework Emulator`](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/testing-authentication-to-your-bot-using-the-bot-framework-emulator/), but didn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue - however just in 1 computer. Same code (deployment) works on other computers.

Comment: @thomasmartinsen Is `ngork` configured in your emulator?

Comment: yes - I also see the error when chatbot is deployed and running in Skype etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mistake in my configuration. I was giving a wrong `ConnectionName`. The connection name should be name of the connection created in `OAuth Connection Settings` section in settings of your Bots Channel Registration. See below screen shot

[image]

Comment: How can I find this screen, I cant find it. Thank you.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah Login to https://portal.azure.com search for Bot Services